# Jquery validator is not working for second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Jquery validator doesn't work for the second time when i submit the form. Validator is not attaching to the submit event for the second time.

I am not submit handler but the valid() function is not invoked either.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#login_form").submit(function() {
            $("#login_form").validate({
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    password: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6
                    }
                },

                messages: {
                    username: {
                        required: "Enter your username"
                                                },
                    password: {
                        required: "Enter your password",
                        minlength: "Password must be minimum 6 characters"
                    },
                },



                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.hide();
                    $('.messagebox').hide();
                    error.appendTo($('#alert-message'));
                    $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');



                },
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                    $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
                }
            });

            if ($("#login_form").valid()) {
                var data1 = $('#login_form').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: data1,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(msg) {

                        if (msg.result == 1) {
                        $('.messagebox').addClass("success-message");
                        $('.message').slideDown('slow');
                        $('#alert-message').text("Logged in.. Redirecting");

                            $('#login_form').fadeOut(5000);
                            window.location = "members.php"
                        } else {    
                        console.log(msg.result);
                        $('.messagebox').hide();
                        $('.messagebox').addClass("error-message");
                        $('#alert-message').html(msg.result);
                         $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Your success function looks weird

Comment: Sorry.I updated it now.

Comment: You have two issues:  1)  The `.validate()` method does not belong inside of a `submit` handler function.  2)  Your `ajax` belongs inside of the `submitHandler` callback function option of the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function() {
        $("#login_form").validate({...
```

You are rebinding validate on each form submit, your validate bindings should only be set one time in the document.ready event, you should always set/bind jquery validate in document ready event and page load only, not again and again on Ajax postbacks. You are correct in firing validation checks multiple times in the form submit event like so though:

```
$("#login_form").submit(function() {
    if ($("#login_form").valid()) {...
```

Here is the fixed code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

         $("#login_form").validate({
            rules: {
                username: {
                    required: true
                },
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                }
            },

            messages: {
                username: {
                    required: "Enter your username"
                                            },
                password: {
                    required: "Enter your password",
                    minlength: "Password must be minimum 6 characters"
                },
            },



            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.hide();
                $('.messagebox').hide();
                error.appendTo($('#alert-message'));
                $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');



            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
            },
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
            }
        });//end validate bindings/settings


    $("#login_form").submit(function() {
                            //fire validation checks
        if ($("#login_form").valid()) {
            var data1 = $('#login_form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: data1,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg) {

                    if (msg.result == 1) {
                    $('.messagebox').addClass("success-message");
                    $('.message').slideDown('slow');
                    $('#alert-message').text("Logged in.. Redirecting");

                        $('#login_form').fadeOut(5000);
                        window.location = "members.php"
                    } else {    
                    console.log(msg.result);
                    $('.messagebox').hide();
                    $('.messagebox').addClass("error-message");
                    $('#alert-message').html(msg.result);
                     $('.messagebox').slideDown('slow');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });

});
```